# Task.Run Ambiguous Parameter Overloads

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm using the Task class in C# and want to pass a predefined method that returns a value and not using lambdas to the `Task.Run` method.

Here is a console app with the code:

```
static int ThreadMethod()
{
    return 42;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<int> t = Task.Run(function:ThreadMethod);
    WriteLine(t.Result);
}
```

However, it is returning this error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)' and 'Task.Run(Func<Task>)'

I tried doing this to fix it and got my expected result:

```
Task<int> t = Task.Run((Func<int>)ThreadMethod);
```

However, I am not sure if I'm doing it right or are there any better solution?

Comment: Func and Action are just delegates. they have nothing just a name ;). use lambda instead. they are anonymous delegates btw. `()=>ThreadMethod()`

Comment: by some tricks, if you dont want to use lambda for whatever reason. you can do this.`Task.Run(function: ThreadMethod)`. but you should change your method signature to this. `static async Task<int> ThreadMethod()`. this is meaningless but it compiles.

Comment: whoah the `async` part made it more confusing. I'm sorry I'm still a noob in multitasking and asynchronous programming in C#

Comment: Anyway, thanks for answering my query. In the mean time I'll just do what you and Cubicle Jockey suggested while looking for more information.

Comment: This Problem has been fixed in C# 7.3 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837722/why-is-the-call-ambiguous-task-runaction-and-task-runfunctask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your .Run argument like in this example. Can be copied and pasted into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<int> t = Task.Run(() => ThreadMethod());
    WriteLine(t.Result);
}

public static int ThreadMethod()
{
    return 42;
}
```

---

If you want to see it as a variable to pass check out below:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    //Func<int> is saying I want a function with no parameters
    //but returns an int. '() =>' this represents a function with 
    //no parameters. It then points to your defined method ThreadMethod
    //Which fits the notions of no parameters and returning an int.

    Func<int> threadMethod = () => ThreadMethod();

    Task<int> t = Task.Run(threadMethod);
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
}

public static int ThreadMethod()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Here is the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) on Func(T), on the left hand menu you can select the different variations of Func() objects.

Comment: Can you further elaborate for me why this is a better way than casting to a (Func<T>)? I just want to better understand it. Or maybe a good reference would really help.

Comment: Updated my answer a bit with a link to the documentation to study.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into all the information you gave and try to grasp it even more.